# How to resolve the access denied channel in hyperledger-fabric and java-sdk

Tags: java, spring-boot, hyperledger-fabric

I am facing a problem. That is when I build and run my java project ([HLF-Java-Sdk](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/fabric-sdks.html)) from the command line `java -jar something.jar` this works perfectly. But when I run my project I mean the `main class as java application` from the `sts ide` it gives error. In log I found that is `grpc error access denied`. After that I give the `sudo permission of the channel`. But it is not working at all. same things are happening.

Error Log:

> java.lang.Exception: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNKNOWN: access denied: channel [Shop] creator org [Org1MSP]
>       at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.sendProposalToPeers(Channel.java:4087) [fabric-sdk-java-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
>       at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.getConfigBlock(Channel.java:845) [fabric-sdk-java-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
>       at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.parseConfigBlock(Channel.java:1728) [fabric-sdk-java-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
>       at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.loadCACertificates(Channel.java:1565) [fabric-sdk-java-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
>       at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.sendProposalToPeers(Channel.java:4006) [fabric-sdk-java-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
>       at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.sendProposal(Channel.java:3979) [fabric-sdk-java-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
>       at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.sendProposalSerially(Channel.java:3904) [fabric-sdk-java-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
>       at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.queryBlockchainInfo(Channel.java:3122) [fabric-sdk-java-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
>       at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.queryBlockchainInfo(Channel.java:3052) [fabric-sdk-java-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
>       at org.hyperledger.fabric.ShopChainServiceImpl.getBlockList(ShopChainServiceImpl.java:361) [classes/:na]
>       at org.hyperledger.fabric.ShopChainServiceImpl.getBlocks(ShopChainServiceImpl.java:298) [classes/:na]
>       at blockchain.controller.ChaincodeController.queryBlocks(ChaincodeController.java:406) [classes/:na]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_242]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_242]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_242]
>   Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNKNOWN: access denied: channel [Shop] creator org [Org1MSP]
>       at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:530) ~[grpc-core-1.18.0.jar:1.18.0]
>       at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$UnaryStreamToFuture.onClose(ClientCalls.java:482) ~[grpc-stub-1.18.0.jar:1.18.0]
>       at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39) ~[grpc-core-1.18.0.jar:1.18.0]
>       at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23) ~[grpc-core-1.18.0.jar:1.18.0]
>       at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40) ~[grpc-core-1.18.0.jar:1.18.0]
>       at io.grpc.internal.CensusStatsModule$StatsClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusStatsModule.java:699) ~[grpc-core-1.18.0.jar:1.18.0]
>       at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39) ~[grpc-core-1.18.0.jar:1.18.0]
>       at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23) ~[grpc-core-1.18.0.jar:1.18.0]
>       at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40) ~[grpc-core-1.18.0.jar:1.18.0]
>       at io.grpc.internal.CensusTracingModule$TracingClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusTracingModule.java:397) ~[grpc-core-1.18.0.jar:1.18.0]
>       at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:459) ~[grpc-core-1.18.0.jar:1.18.0]
>       at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$300(ClientCallImpl.java:63) ~[grpc-core-1.18.0.jar:1.18.0]
>       at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.close(ClientCallImpl.java:546) ~[grpc-core-1.18.0.jar:1.18.0]
>       at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.access$600(ClientCallImpl.java:467) ~[grpc-core-1.18.0.jar:1.18.0]
>       at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:584) ~[grpc-core-1.18.0.jar:1.18.0]
>       at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37) ~[grpc-core-1.18.0.jar:1.18.0]
>       at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123) ~[grpc-core-1.18.0.jar:1.18.0]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_242]

Is there any suggestion that I can follow to get rid of this stuck.
HyperLedger version is 1.4.1

Comment: Are you using the Admin or User certificate?

Comment: @Rodolfo admin certificate

Comment: Looks like you reach the node but the it denies your access, without considering connection issues I would suggest you to double check your channel configtx.
Do you can run commands from cli using the same certificates? maybe you had regenerated the certificates and dont update the channel config.
You can use peer channel fetch to get the config block and see if everything is Ok.

Answer (score 0):

The way of solution of the problem I have found that is

- when creating the `usercontext` I mean generate or read `admin.ser` file which is
  write in the directory or read from the directory if already created.
- So for my case where `/some_dir/user/org1/admin.ser` this file is created with no read permission. That's why I am getting permission denied error. After changing the permission or if I change the directory where have the read/write permission it working perfectly.
- so the change is basically I have done from also `code` to read/write the `admin.ser`

> String directoryPath = System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "users" + File.separator
>                   + userContext.getAffiliation();
>   // Just I am sharing my code. For understanding